# coreldraw X5: multiple transparancy gradients

Tags: transparency, corel-draw

Is there quick and easy (non destructive) way to get multiple transparency gradients on one object?

For example I want a black-white gradient from bottom to top as well as top to bottom, or variants of that.

There is a similar question posted, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Sorry not a Corel user, but I have to ask... couldn't you simply use a black-white-black gradient for what you describe? Why do you need transparency?

Comment: Hi, I dont want the gradients to be symmetric per se. For example one line of transparancy might run with 40 degrees angle to which I add different transparancy gradient with a different angle. Ofcourse this is easily achieved by chaning the transparancy, then convert to bitmap, and then repeat the process with the different gradient of choice. But this is not flexible enought for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand the exact result you expect but there are some options.

**1)** You can use a mesh fill, where you can not only change color of one node but the transparency itself. As the mesh can get complicated use a mesh of a simple rectangle and put it inside your shape.

**2)** Use a bitmap as the pattern you need as transparent.

**3)** Edit your gradient. For the case you mention "from bottom to top as well as top to bottom" simply choose linear and there is a cup icon on the properties bar. Clic on it and you now can choose several steps to that gradient. position and color. It is more complicated if you want diferent angles but it is a starting point.

**4)** Stalk objects with diferent blending modes. Probably some transparencies can be simulated this way.

Here are the examples and a hint of the configuration. All the shapes are still in vector and completly editable:

[image]