# What CorelDraw Effect or Tool is Used to Achieve Transparency

Tags: vector, effects, corel-draw, symbols

I am new to CorelDraw in that I come from the Adobe world.

At the moment, I am working with a CorelDraw file that has several brush-like Symbols. These Symbols are styled, but I cannot see how.

For example, in the image below, the cloud on the left is what I get if I duplicate the Symbol in the Symbol Manager window, make a new instance of it and place it on white background.
On the right is what I get if I copy-paste the existing cloud used as part of the design.

[image]

Essentially, my question is how can I style the left to get the version on the right? I have tried the Transparency tool and the Lens effect. The former looks close, but I am not sure that it is accurate. The Lens effect modifies the color to something unacceptable.

Speaking of the Lens effect, when I select the original Symbol used in the design, the status bar seems to say that there is Lens effect applied to it. However, when I go to adjust this effect, it tells me that none is applied.

[image]

Lastly, is there a way to inspect the styles that are applied to an Object or Symbol?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13459/coreldraw-x5-multiple-transparancy-gradients/73574#73574

Answer (score 2):

The style you showed in the picture looks like `transparency` to me. You can check the properties of an object through Object Properties panel.[image: capture]